# + (Class)layerClass won't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

I'm building an OpenGL application and on eaglview.m `+ (Class)layerClass` wont work.

If i try to run it I get:

```
"Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CAEAGLLayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GLView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status"
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 25):

You need to add the OpenGL and potentially the QuartzCore frameworks to the target to link them.

Comment: Any way of resolving the problem without adding QuartzCore? The reason I ask is that a default OpenGL Game application does not include the QuartzCore framework, so presumably it can be avoided (unless it is somehow embedded in the GLKit framework). Can it be avoided?

Comment: the specific error presented in the problem is a problem of a specific class not existing. that class is part of CoreAnimation which is part of the QuartzCore framework