# "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CAEAGLLayer", referenced from: objc-class-ref in DBSignatureView.o" Not Resolving

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a app , in one of the module ,which is going to import two Libraries.
1) OpenGLES.framework
2) QuartzCore.framework.

for the purpose of drawing. But I have a drawing app of this separate which works fine . when I add this to my app , which gives "build failed".

I have gone through many of the links to rectify such as `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953168/symbols-not-found-for-architecture-armv6/10415850#10415850`

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251111/classlayerclass-wont-work
```

Even removed the libraries and  I added again the config as stated in these links. But still I'm getting the same errors.

This is my Error Page .

```
Ld /Users/kumaralakshmanna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Checking_del-bseuzbpwlbzpxvdzdamarjieapuz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Checking_del.app/Checking_del normal i386
    cd /Users/kumaralakshmanna/Documents/IOS_Worksapace/Checking_del
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -L/Users/kumaralakshmanna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Checking_del-bseuzbpwlbzpxvdzdamarjieapuz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/kumaralakshmanna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Checking_del-bseuzbpwlbzpxvdzdamarjieapuz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/kumaralakshmanna/Documents/IOS_Worksapace/Checking_del -filelist /Users/kumaralakshmanna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Checking_del-bseuzbpwlbzpxvdzdamarjieapuz/Build/Intermediates/Checking_del.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Checking_del.build/Objects-normal/i386/Checking_del.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -o /Users/kumaralakshmanna/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Checking_del-bseuzbpwlbzpxvdzdamarjieapuz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Checking_del.app/Checking_del

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/kumaralakshmanna/Documents/IOS_Worksapace/Checking_del/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/kumaralakshmanna/Documents/IOS_Worksapace/Checking_del/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/kumaralakshmanna/Documents/IOS_Worksapace/Checking_del/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/kumaralakshmanna/Documents/IOS_Worksapace/Checking_del/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CAEAGLLayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DBSignatureView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EAGLContext", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DBSignatureView.o
  "_glBindFramebufferOES", referenced from:
      -[DBSignatureView createFramebuffer] in DBSignatureView.o
      -[DBSignatureView erase] in DBSignatureView.o
      -[DBSignatureView renderLineFromPoint:toPoint:] in DBSignatureView.o
  "_glBindRenderbufferOES", referenced from:
      -[DBSignatureView createFramebuffer] in DBSignatureView.o
      -[DBSignatureView erase] in DBSignatureView.o
      -[DBSignatureView renderLineFromPoint:toPoint:] in DBSignatureView.o
  "_glBindTexture", referenced from:
      -[DBSignatureView commonInit] in DBSignatureView.o
  "_glBlendFunc", referenced from:
      -[DBSignatureView commonInit] in DBSignatureView.o
  "_glCheckFramebufferStatusOES", referenced from:
      -[DBSignatureView createFramebuffer] in DBSignatureView.o
  "_glClear", referenced from:
      -[DBSignatureView erase] in DBSignatureView.o
  "_glClearColor", referenced from:
      -[DBSignatureView erase] in DBSignatureView.o
  "_glColor4f", referenced from:
      -[DBSignatureView setBrushColorWithRed:green:blue:] in DBSignatureView.o
  "_glDeleteFramebuffersOES", referenced from:
      -[DBSignatureView destroyFramebuffer] in DBSignatureView.o
  "_glDeleteRenderbuffersOES", referenced from:
      -[DBSignatureView destroyFramebuffer] in DBSignatureView.o
  "_glDeleteTextures", referenced from:
      -[DBSignatureView dealloc] in DBSignatureView.o
  "_glDisable", referenced from:
      -[DBSignatureView commonInit] in DBSignatureView.o
  "_glDrawArrays", referenced from:
      -[DBSignatureView renderLineFromPoint:toPoint:] in DBSignatureView.o
  "_glEnable", referenced from:
      -[DBSignatureView commonInit] in DBSignatureView.o
  "_glEnableClientState", referenced from:
      -[DBSignatureView commonInit] in DBSignatureView.o
  "_glFramebufferRenderbufferOES", referenced from:
      -[DBSignatureView createFramebuffer] in DBSignatureView.o
  "_glGenFramebuffersOES", referenced from:
      -[DBSignatureView createFramebuffer] in DBSignatureView.o
  "_glGenRenderbuffersOES", referenced from:
      -[DBSignatureView createFramebuffer] in DBSignatureView.o
  "_glGenTextures", referenced from:
      -[DBSignatureView commonInit] in DBSignatureView.o
  "_glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES", referenced from:
      -[DBSignatureView createFramebuffer] in DBSignatureView.o
  "_glMatrixMode", referenced from:
      -[DBSignatureView commonInit] in DBSignatureView.o
  "_glOrthof", referenced from:
      -[DBSignatureView commonInit] in DBSignatureView.o
  "_glPointSize", referenced from:
      -[DBSignatureView commonInit] in DBSignatureView.o
  "_glReadPixels", referenced from:
      -[DBSignatureView upsideDownImageRepresenation] in DBSignatureView.o
```

Is anything wrong with the compatibility of libraries ...? plese do needful

Comment: do you have them in Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries? does this error exists on real device too?

Comment: @medvedNick Thanks for the response , I haven't check with the device.

Comment: @medvedNick No issues with the device . i got it .. Thank You

Comment: this usually happens with custom libraries - when you build some library by yourself only for one architecture - so you have error while linking on simulator and no issues on device. The strange thing in your case is that this is OpenGL lib. Maybe, you are adding it into project wrong way. Try re-adding it from project settings menu