# xcode 5 dealloc void ARC Error

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, dealloc

I get an error (ARC forbids explicit message send of 'dealloc'), if I write:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    self.slider = nil;
    self.tabBar = nil;
    [super dealloc];
 }
```

Hope anyone can help me.
Thanks a lot for answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `[super dealloc]`, it's automatic under ARC.

Should be just:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    self.slider = nil;
    self.tabBar = nil;
}
```

Comment: I tried, but if I do it, I'll get 2 another errors =(

Comment: If I'll run the app: 1st error:  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CAEAGLLayer",     referenced from: objc-class-ref in EAGLView.o

Comment: 2nd error: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Those are unrelated to your `dealloc` issue and could probably be another question. The answer for those is probably just that you need to add the OpenGL and QuartzCore frameworks to your project (or target). Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251111/classlayerclass-wont-work

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I have no errors. But if I'll open the app on the iOS Simulator (7.1) the app crashes after loading the launch image =(

Comment: Ok, well you should accept this answer, and ask another question with your newest crash.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it. Many thanks for your help. Greatings from Germany

Comment: Setting those two to `nil` is also almost certainly unneeded in ARC.